# making a class without layout

Tags: android, image, layout, android-canvas

I am wondering if I can create a class that has no layout (xml) that you don't have to set it on a setcontentview. For clarification, I would like to to have a background picture for my class without creating a layout or xml on it. I just want to have a class. I want to have a background named triviabackground.png (I want this PNG file to be  my background picture).

Can you show me how to code it, or provide me with a reference to a tutorial?

```
public class Trivia extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

i mean like canvas?

Comment: Why you do not set background on layout?

Comment: i so  have many xml file on my project. and i just want to have a picture background on that class

Comment: you must have a layout in order to set a background.

Comment: you just take an imageview in your layout and set layout in activity. thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create Activity without a Layout. Layouts **can** be **used** by your objects, but are absolutely NOT mandatory. But if you want any backgrounds then you cannot have them alone as background is part of layout. You do not need XML layout file - you can create it directly from code if you need.

**EDIT***

```
FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout();
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.background );
setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: You create `ViewGroup` type of object, like `FrameLayout` in your onCreate, set Background property and set this ViewGroup object as your Activity's `setContentView()`

Comment: i mean like creating a canvas

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : ViewGroup needs layout as well.

Comment: @nice : That Canvas you are talking about called View in android.

Comment: @SoheilSetayeshi ViewGroup is abstract class. any *Layout class works fine without any childs. Please learn things first prior starting to give further advices.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : I know it is abstract but its contents need layout if you want to have something visible

Comment: no it does not. empty Layout is perfectly fine and you can set background on it, which is what OP wants.

Comment: The main question is a paradox itself. We can't see anything that is not a view.

Comment: And as you can see in the question , he don't want to use any xml or layouts which is impossible.

Comment: Yes, layout is mandatory to display anything but it does not mean you need any XML files for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an activity without any view but you can't see anything that is not exist ;) background is a view itself and every View needs layout